# Is there a possibility of frame dragging inside the event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, frame-dragging

Is there a possibility of frame dragging inside the event horizon? If frame dragging is related with gravity and space and as the black hole fills a space and produces a gravitational effect that could attract a mass not neccessarly orthogonally to the black hole center could the effect of frame dragging as a effect be possibly extended beyond the black hole event horizon or the part of the space occupied by the black hole should be threated as frame dragging free?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, frame dragging is strong inside the event horizon. [For the equatorial plane of a Kerr metric it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging#Mathematical_derivation)
$$\Omega =\frac{r_s \alpha c}{r^3+\alpha^2 r + r_s\alpha^2}$$
where $r_s=2GM/c^2$ and $\alpha = J/mc$. Note that for $r=0$ (which corresponds to the ring singularity) it is $\Omega= c/ \alpha > 0$.